# My SublimeLinter SublimeLinter-contrib-tslint package stopped working today

Tags: sublimelinter

My SublimeLinter SublimeLinter-contrib-tslint package stopped working today on my mac.

I uninstalled the package and reinstalled it.  I insured my tslint was in my path and runs from my terminal fine. I put SublimeLinter into debug mode and get the following in my console, where it appears to be attempting to run tslint:

> SublimeLinter: SublimeLinter.sublime-package:252: detected syntax:
>   typescript [2018-03-03 16:56:41,513 - INFO     -
>   SublimeLinter.sublime_linter] detected syntax: typescript
>   SublimeLinter: #3 SublimeLinter.sublime-package:782: 'tslint' is
>   linting 'vendor.ts' [2018-03-03 16:56:41,523 - INFO     -
>   SublimeLinter.lint.linter] 'tslint' is linting 'vendor.ts'
>   SublimeLinter: #3 SublimeLinter.sublime-package:1200: tslint:
>   vendor.ts ['/usr/local/bin/tslint', '@'] [2018-03-03 16:56:41,532 -
>   INFO     - SublimeLinter.lint.linter] tslint: vendor.ts
>   ['/usr/local/bin/tslint', '@'] SublimeLinter: #3
>   SublimeLinter.sublime-package:1203: tslint: cwd:
>   /Users/johnskinner/Documents/dev/optiosurgical/api/src/db [2018-03-03
>   16:56:41,532 - INFO     - SublimeLinter.lint.linter] tslint: cwd:
>   /Users/johnskinner/Documents/dev/optiosurgical/api/src/db
>   SublimeLinter: #3 SublimeLinter.sublime-package:809: tslint output:
>       No valid rules have been specified [2018-03-03 16:56:42,236 - INFO     - SublimeLinter.lint.linter] tslint output:
>       No valid rules have been specified SublimeLinter: #3 SublimeLinter.sublime-package:850: tslint: No match for line: 'No
>   valid rules have been specified' [2018-03-03 16:56:42,236 - INFO     -
>   SublimeLinter.lint.linter] tslint: No match for line: 'No valid rules
>   have been specified' reloading settings
>   Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I'm pretty sure it is related to the message I got about the linter updating to SublimeLinter 4.0.1.  I think what we're seeing is this bug:
https://github.com/lavrton/SublimeLinter-contrib-tslint/issues/25

I went into Preferences-> 'Package Settings' -> SublimeLinter and turned on debug

```
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{
  "debug": true,
}
```

and saw I was getting this error in the console

```
SublimeLinter: #47 SublimeLinter.sublime-package:850: tslint: No match for line: 'No valid rules have been specified'
```

I ended up having to add a command to specify the location of my tslint.json, as described in the docs https://github.com/lavrton/SublimeLinter-contrib-tslint (I never had to do this before, but just setting config_filename doesn't seem to be enough.)

```
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{
  "debug": true,
  "gutter_theme": "warning",
  "linters": {
    "tslint": {
      "disable": false,
       "args": ["--config", "${folder}/tslint.json"],
      "excludes": [
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "config_filename": "tslint.json"
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect that there is a cleaner solution, I don't like having to set that location, but this got things going for me again...

Comment: Specifying the path worked for me as well. The path should be `/Users/<username>/<path-to-folder>/tslint.json` i.e. the full system file path on Unix. And probably with `\\` on Windows.

Comment: A full path will work, but using ${folder} should find the root of your current project.  Which is helpful if you have multiple projects with different linting settings.

Comment: I know it should. But it didn't for me :)